Baremetal /proc/cpuinfo
I'm trying to check the revision code of a Raspberry Pi 4b, but the only instructions I can find say to get it from /proc/cpuinfo, but that's a Linux-specific answer. So far I haven't been able to find the documentation of what physical address I can read from to get the same information. Can anyone point me to a document that will tell me that, and/or an example source file that reads that value directly?

I would ask on the bare metal section of the Pi forum https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewforum.php?f=72

I found the answer in the firmware wiki (thanks to this answer). The revision number comes from mailbox 0 channel 8:

Get board revision

Tag: 0x00010002
Request:

Length: 0


Response:

Length: 4
Value:

u32: board revision






